# Write a file to a remote location using Java with network path or drive?

Tags: java, file, io, windows-share

I have shared a folder on my server using Windows sharing. On another computer, where I am running my code on, I have mapped a network drive pointing to that folder.

In my code, I transfer files from my local computer to my server every now and then. Something like this:

```
File srcFile = new File("C:\\test.mpg");
File destFile = new File(...);

// error checking
FileUtils.moveFile(srcFile, destFile);
```

For `destFile`, which approach should I use? My current approach:

```
File destFile = new File("Z:\\folder\\test.mpg");
```

or using a network path:

```
File destFile = new File("\\192.168.123.123\\folder\\test.mpg");
```

---

I ask this because recently I have encountered cases where the file transfer fails because my program is unable to write to my network drive because it is not logged on, and I have to manually go to the drive and enter my credentials and enable "Stay connected" option.

Answer (score 8):

You can use mapped drives or full network paths equivalently; Java doesn't care and just passes the file name on to the OS. Note that if you're using a network path, you need `\\\\` at the beginning.

Comment: Can the mapped drivers be used by a windows service (like tomcat service)?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library to access a Windows SMB share in Java. Using it, you could do something like the following:

```
String smbUrl = "smb://username:password@server/share/file";
SmbFileOutputStream fos = new SmbFileOutputStream(new SmbFile(smbURL));
```

Comment: if you have domain then you have to use it like domain;user:password e.g String smbUrl = "smb://domain;username:password@server/share/file";

Comment: but how we will be moving file from source to destination ? I think your code tells us to connect password protected folder but how to move a file to that folder, As FileUutils.moveFile() accecpt parameter of File type only not of SmbFile